# No solver when accessing using Optaplanner REST API

Tags: optaplanner, kie-workbench, kie-wb, kie-server

I created Optaplanner project and deploy it to kie execution server using kie-workbench.

Upon making REST call [GET] /containers/{containerId}/solvers, solver list is empty.

```
{
  "type" : "SUCCESS",
  "msg" : "Solvers list successfully retrieved from container 'org.optaplanner.examples:cloud-balancing:1.0'",
  "result" : {
    "solver-instance-list" : {
      "solver" : [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have created solver configuration file $PROJECT_DIR/src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing/solver/cloudSolverConfig.solver.xml.

I am using version 6.5.0.final for optaplanner, kie-wb.

Any idea?

Regards,
Nick

Comment: Did you do it like in the optacloud video or like in the course scheduling video? OptaPlanner Execution Server is still young, we made many improvements for 7.0 Beta's already.

Comment: I referred to https://www.optaplanner.org/download/releaseNotes/releaseNotes6.4.html.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a REST call that creates a solver first.

Comment: I get the following error when making call to create solver: Error creating solver factory for solver: The solverConfigResource (org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing/solver/cloudSolverConfig.solver.xml) does not exist as a classpath resource in the classLoader (org.drools.core.common.ProjectClassLoader@fde99e0). The xml file is under src/main/resources/org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing.

Comment: For your info, I switched to 7.0Beta6.

Comment: Lookup the jar that you're trying to deploy in the (local) maven repository. Unzip it and see if you can find `org/optaplanner/examples/cloudbalancing/solver/cloudSolverC‌​onfig.solver.xml` in there.

Comment: Yes, the file is there.

Comment: Thank you for your help. After I added a Process and re-deployed the project, the system started to create tables for the entities. After everything starts to work.